# "Insufficient resources" error with Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

Any idea on what can cause this error, everytime I execute a query?

The DB is about 2GB.

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, isn't "Insufficient resources" quite self-explanatory?

Answer (score 4):

The maximum size for a single Access 2007 DB is 2GB minus the space for required System Objects. [Ref](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288631).

Do you regularly [compact](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/hp051874491033.aspx) your database? A large Access DB is often a symptom of not compacting.

> Click on the round Office button
>   that you should see in the
>   upper left corner. Then click on
>   Manage in the list. You should see
>   Compact and Repair Database at the top
>   of this listing.
>
> [NOTE: Although the maximum size for a
>   single database file is 2GB, you can
>   work around this limitation by using a
>   split database. A front-end database
>   file can point to thousands of
>   back-end database files, each of which
>   could be as large as 2GB. For more
>   information, see the topic, Split a
>   database.]

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the limits of your mdb filesize:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HP051868081033.aspx

Comment: Actually that message happens when you do exceed the 2 Gb limits of an Access database.